# how to retrieve part of a string in java?

Tags: java, string

I am designing a chat applet. In this, a user will append his name to the beginning of the message that he sends to the other user. In the window of other user, I want to retrieve the appended user name from that string. How do I do that? The message sent by the user is as follows :

```
final_msg = user_name + ": " + user_message
```

Hence I want to know how to retrieve the user_name string only. Is there a function that can retrieve a substring upto the first ":"? I dont want to use final_msg.split(":"), because there is a possiblity that the user_message contains ":", which will then give me an array of strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quick tip:

use `indexOf` method to find first index of ':' character, then do a `substring`() call.

```
String userName = final_msg.substring(0,final_msg.indexOf(':'));
```

Edit:
Consider renaming your variable from `final_msg` to `finalMsg` - just because, that is the Java style. Normally "_" appear in Java Constant names

Comment: Speaking of variable names... you put `s` where I assume you meant `final_msg`

Answer (score 6):

You can use split and give it a maximum limit. ie:
`final_msg.split(":", 2)[0]`

Comment: +1: That's a very good suggestion as it is easy to get right.

Comment: This is much easier than the other suggestion. Not to mention easier to read later.